# Estimate for Cognitive Services in Norwegian language?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Does anyone have a timeplan or an estimate for when Cognitive Services and/or LUIS will be available in the Norwegian language? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really related to programming... I would imagine you have to ask Microsoft marketing.

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably specific release dates are not available.  However, You can provide feedback and suggest features/ideas for Microsoft Cognitive Services on their feedback forum.
https://cognitive.uservoice.com/